# how to add header.vue and footer.vue in another component in vue js with laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, header, footer

I have header.vue and footer.vue and i want to add it in Home.vue but when i am adding it taking huge space below header and footer. I add header.vue below   and footer.vue above  but taking huge space. why it is happening?

Home.vue

```
  <template>

     <div id="app">
        <v-app id="healthy">

 <vue-header></vue-header>

    <v-row align="center" justify="center" >
      <v-col cols="12" sm="8"  md="4" >

        <v-card class="elevation-12" justify="center" align="center">
          <v-toolbar color="primary" dark flat>

            <v-toolbar-title ></v-toolbar-title>

          </v-toolbar>

          <h3 class="mt-5"> What you want ? </h3>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-form justify="center">
              <v-btn color="primary" rounded  class="mt-12 mb-12" v-on:click="dash">Dashboard</v-btn>

              <v-btn color="primary" rounded  class="mb-12" v-on:click="showAlert">Contact</v-btn>

            </v-form>               
          </v-card-text>

        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

 <vue-footer></vue-footer>  

    </v-app>
  </div>
```

The image is shown below. why huge space is taking below header or footer. am i placing the header and footer in right place???[image]

Footer.vue

```
 <template>
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-footer  height="auto" color="#CDCDCD" class="font-weight-medium">
            <v-col class="text-center white--text" cols="12">
                <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="float: center;">  Google </a>             
            </v-col>
        </v-footer>
    </v-app>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think this is a CSS problem caused by Vuetify can you provide a fully working example using CodeSandbox

Comment: but i have not use CSS and added the footer.vue  code also. @MiladDehghan